# can a map be defined from some domain to the image of itself?

Tags: functions

I want to define a bijective map. In my case injectivity is guaranteed. However, the map is not surjective. Can I restrict the co-domain to the image of the map? For example, let $A$ be a set, $f: A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not surjective. Can I define a map in one of the following ways:
$$ f: A \rightarrow image(A) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $$
or 
$$ f: A \rightarrow f(A)$$
or
$$ f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}|_{f(A)}.$$

If I can, then sujectivity is immediate by definition. Since, $f$ is also injective, it gives me the desired result that $f$ is bijective.

Comment: You can and this is the way you can generate bijective maps from injective maps.

Comment: Thanks Kavi. Can you please provide a reference of a book or paper where this technique is used?

Answer (score 1):

Well you sort of can, but if you are absolutely precise you actually have to define a new map (since otherwise, your definition becomes circular: to define a map, you need a codomain, but to define your codomain, you need a map).

So go like this:

We have an original map $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ and know it is injective. Let $B:= image(f) = f(A)$ be its image. Then the *new map*

$\hat f: A \mapsto B$, $\hat f(a) := f(a)$ for all $a \in A$

is bijective. Even most mathematicians would not really distinguish between $f$ and $\hat f$ or just write something like "restrict $f$ to its image" and continue to call the new map $f$, but for a rigorous definition, one would have to do something like this.